# How to migrate my flutter web app to the new Google Identity Services?

Tags: flutter, google-oauth, google-signin, google-identity

My flutter web app uses the 'google_sign_in' package to authenticate the users. I received an email telling me to migrate to the new Google Identity Services (GIS) before March 31, 2023. I could not find any information about how to migrate my flutter project. Will there be a new 'google_sign_in' package for GIS? Otherwise, what should I do? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open issue on the Dart/Flutter tracking this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/88084.

Once the Dart/Flutter library is updated to use the new Google Identity Services, you should be able to update your code to use the new library.